# To find the impulse repsonse using the difference equation

Tags: discrete-signals, infinite-impulse-response, homework

A causal linear time-invariant filter has transfer function
[image]

a) Denote the input signal by x[n] and the output signal by y[n]. Find the difference
equations for the filter.

f) Find the impulse response of the system. (Eliminate j (the imaginary unit) from
your answer.)

I used the partial fractions method and obtained the following solution.

[image] However it was time consuming. Is there a way that I can simplify this difference equation to get the impulse response of the IIR filter to get the same solution. Any help will be appreciated(as I am not aware of solving by difference equations)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real shortcut for computing the impulse response. Partial fractions is the standard way to do it. However, in the case of a second-order transfer function as in your example, the result can be found in tables of $\mathcal{Z}$-transform pairs. E.g., if you use the last two correspondence of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs), you can pretty quickly write down the result.

By the way, your result can't be correct (at least not for negative $n$), because you know that the system is causal, so its impulse response must be zero for $n<0$.

Comment: L thanks. That saved a lot of working steps in my problem